# XML - XSLT Transformation - producing special "<? ... ?>" tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming some XML data to fit into document that is in a format of"Excel XML Spreadsheet 2003"

It all works ok, but I have a problem with generating the proper header of the result file.
It should basically be in a form of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

 <!-- end of header here and the transformation data goes below -->

<Workbook>
```

the XSLT file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

but in the result file the `<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>`line is missing.

I understand that `<? ...?>` is a special tag - so may question is how can it be produced by the XSLT

Thanks

Comment: what programming language are you using? If it is php, try disabling the short_tags from php.ini

Comment: @sAc - thanks for the comment, I was not php, I was looking for general xsl approach and Alejandro provided the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With any input, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" />
```

Comment: thanks Alejandro, I had not idea what xsl: tag name to look for

Comment: @kristof: You are wellcome! It's also a good thing to study XSLT specs in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt